# Slim does not display as expected. I want to show on browser that "Hello, It's Nextflow"

Tags: php, slim

The following code segment does not display `Hello It's, Nextflow` as I had intended.

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use \Slim\App;
$app = new App;
$app->get('/hello/', function() {
   echo "Hello, It's Nextflow";
});
?>
```

Comment: Please add code, not screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `run` method on `Slim` application to make it work. Add the following code to the bottom of your code:

```
$app->run();
```

Full file will be:

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use \Slim\App;
$app = new App;
$app->get('/hello/', function() {
   echo "Hello, It's Nextflow";
});
// Run application
$app->run();
?>
```